# Unquote character in `.vars` argument in `fabletools::autoplot_tbl_ts()`

Tags: r, fabletools

If I want to use a character vector in dplyr, I can do this:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
  library(rlang)
  library(tibble)
  
  my_var <- "mpg"
  my_data <- as_tibble(mtcars)
  
  my_data |>
    select(!!my_var)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Likewise, I want to do the same in `fabletools::autoplot.tbl_ts()`:

```r
library(testthat)
  set.seed(12345)
  df <- tsibble::tsibble(
    qtr = tsibble::yearquarter("2010 Q1") + 0:59,
    y = rnorm(60),
    index = qtr
  )
  dv_name <- "y"
  
  actual <- fabletools::autoplot(df, !!dv_name)
  expected <- fabletools::autoplot(df, y)
  expect_equal(actual, expected)
#> Error: `actual` not equal to `expected`
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Seems like the bang-bang `!!` is not the right choice here. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `dv_name` is a string, not a symbol. Use

```
fabletools::autoplot(df, .data[[dv_name]])
```

That will look up the string column name in the data. The `.data` object is a special pronoun provided by rlang. The fact that this works with `select()` is kind of specific to that function. You can use both

```
select(mtcars, mpg)
select(mtcars, "mpg")
```

But using a string for a column name doesn't work the same in most other functions.

you could also translate the string into a symbol and then use `!!`. For example

```
fabletools::autoplot(df, !!rlang::ensym(dv_name))
```